# Issue With Button setOnClickListener Function Call

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a problem with my setOnClickListener method for one of the buttons in my code. What basically happens is that I call a typeFinder inside the setOnClickListener method, but the first time I press the button the values do not get updated. I have used the debugger and from my understanding what happens is that even though the function is called, the program does not actually go through the function until after setOnClickListener, which means when I press the button the second time it has the right values to show from the previous button press. I have tried using TypesTask as well (as seen in commented part at the bottom of the page), but doing so resulted in the same outcome. 
Here is the code for the class:

```
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    private DatabaseReference myRef;
    private ArrayList<String> recipesList = new ArrayList<String>();
    private String[] types = {"pizza", "ice cream", "sandwich", "salad", "steak"};
    private void typeFinder(String type) {
        myRef.orderByChild("type").equalTo(type).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                // This method is called once with the initial value and again
                // whenever data at this location is updated.
                String word = "";
                boolean wordAdded = false;
                String value = dataSnapshot.getValue().toString();
                for (int i = 0; i < value.length(); i++) {
                    if (wordAdded == false) {
                        if (value.charAt(i) == '=') {
                            recipesList.add(word);
                            wordAdded = true;
                            word = "";
                        } else if (value.charAt(i) != '{' && value.charAt(i) != ',') {
                            if (word.length() == 0 && value.charAt(i) == ' ') {
                            } else {
                                word = word + value.charAt(i);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if (value.charAt(i) == '}')
                        if (i + 2 == value.length()) {
                            wordAdded = false;
                            break;
                        } else
                            wordAdded = false;
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
                // Failed to read value
                Log.w(TAG, "Failed to read value.", error.toException());
            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        Button saladsB = (Button) findViewById(R.id.saladButton);
        Button pizzaB = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pizzaButton);
        Button iceCreamB = (Button) findViewById(R.id.iceCreamButton);
        Button steakB = (Button) findViewById(R.id.steakButton);
        Button sandwichB = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sandwichButton);
        final TextView testTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.test_text_view);
        testTextView.setText(Integer.toString(recipesList.size()));
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        saladsB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // recipesList.clear();
             //   t.typeFinder("salad")
                  typeFinder("salad");
           //     new TypesTask().execute("salad");
                String recipes = "";
                for (int i = 0; i < recipesList.size(); i++) {
                    recipes = recipes + recipesList.get(i) + "\n";
                }
                testTextView.setText(recipes);
              //  Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ListviewActivity.class);
              //  intent.putStringArrayListExtra("FOOD_LIST", recipesList);
              //  startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
    /*
    public class TypesTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        }
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
            typeFinder(params[0]);
            return null;
        }
    }
    */
}
```

Here is the xml for the page

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.thevash.recipes.MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="810dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="458dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/test_text_view"
            android:layout_width="585dp"
            android:layout_height="248dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="TextView"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="-377dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/saladButton"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:text="Salads"
        tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/pizzaButton"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:text="Pizzas"
        tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="52dp"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/iceCreamButton"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:text="ice cream"
        tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/pizzaButton"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/pizzaButton"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/pizzaButton" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/steakButton"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:text="steaks"
        tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/iceCreamButton"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/iceCreamButton"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/iceCreamButton" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/sandwichButton"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:text="sandwiches"
        tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/steakButton"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/steakButton"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/steakButton" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Can you reduce this to a [mcve]?

Comment: I am not sure if I can since I am connecting to the database to pull out the values.

Comment: Can you move to `myRef.orderByChild("type").equalTo(type).addValueEventListener` to onCreate for initialization first to check it works?

Comment: Putting the that function inside onCreate did solve the problem. The only issue is that now I need to manually input the type, which is a problem, since I want the user to choose the type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this using TypesTask but you need to modify TypesTask class like below

```
public class TypesTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    }
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        typeFinder(params[0]);
        return null;
    }
   @Override
   onPostExecute(Void result){
      String recipes = "";
      for (int i = 0; i < recipesList.size(); i++) {
                recipes = recipes + recipesList.get(i) + "\n";
      }
      testTextView.setText(recipes);
   }
}
```

and your onClick should be like this

```
saladsB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

          new TypesTask().execute("salad");

        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This almost did the trick. I just had to make the program sleep for a second after calling typeFinder to give it enough time to update the variables. It worked perfectly after that.
One thing to note is that  testTextView.setText(recipes) cannot be called there, since it is only accessible inside onCreate(), but I tested the output another way, and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Your method in which you are building the reciepeList is an asynchronous call. You need to update the changes to Ui after the OnSuccess() call of EventListener. Relocate the Ui updation code to OnDataChange See the code below :

```
private void typeFinder(String type) {
    myRef.orderByChild("type").equalTo(type).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            // This method is called once with the initial value and again
            // whenever data at this location is updated.
            String word = "";
            boolean wordAdded = false;
            String value = dataSnapshot.getValue().toString();
            for (int i = 0; i < value.length(); i++) {
                if (wordAdded == false) {
                    if (value.charAt(i) == '=') {
                        recipesList.add(word);
                        wordAdded = true;
                        word = "";
                    } else if (value.charAt(i) != '{' && value.charAt(i) != ',') {
                        if (word.length() == 0 && value.charAt(i) == ' ') {
                        } else {
                            word = word + value.charAt(i);
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (value.charAt(i) == '}')
                    if (i + 2 == value.length()) {
                        wordAdded = false;
                        break;
                    } else
                        wordAdded = false;
            }

         // Update the Ui Here
           String recipes = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < recipesList.size(); i++) {
                recipes = recipes + recipesList.get(i) + "\n";
            }
            this.testTextView.setText(recipes);
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
            // Failed to read value
            Log.w(TAG, "Failed to read value.", error.toException());
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This method worked as well. I did not need to add sleep for this to work. Similarly to the other answer, one thing to note is that testTextView.setText(recipes) cannot be called there, since it is only accessible inside onCreate(). But it did work during my tests.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments both of the answers provided work. I either had to add the UI update to the typeFinder function itself, or use AsyncTask to update the UI inside onPostExecute method. For the latter I had to put the program to sleep for one second after the line typeFinder(params[0]) to give it enough time to update the variables.